# 'docker-compose.yml' is invalid because: Invalid top-level property "wordpress"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

While running `docker-compose up` getting the below error:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Invalid top-level property "wordpress". Valid top-level sections for this Compose file are: version, services, networks, volumes, and extensions starting with "x-".

You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version (e.g "2.2" or "3.3") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/
```

**Infra Details:**

- Docker

```
Docker version 23.0.0, build e92dd87
```

- docker-compose (installed using `apt-get install docker-compose`)

```
docker-compose version 1.25.0, build unknown
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'

wordpress:
  image: wordpress
  links:
    - db:mysql

db:
  image: mariadb
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '<a secure password>'
```

Answer (score 0):

On the top level you should have `services` and only then the services themselves. Something like this:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    links:
      - db:mysql

  db:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '<a secure password>'
```